# 503 error on fetch call when deployed to heroku but not local

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, puppeteer

**The issue:** When I send a specific get request to my server after deploying to heroku, I get a 503 error every time and the app doesn't complete the action that I'm expecting on hitting submit. The request is specifically meant to trigger puppeteer screenshots code and return a zip file with screenshots to client. This works perfectly as expected locally, it's only once it's deployed that it fails.

**Notable error(s):** My heroku logs are producing a request timeout error about halfway through the screenshots, code is H12. It's not clear to me right now what the cause of this would be, and therefore what the solution should be (or even how best to go about finding out).

**The app:** I've built an internal team app that takes in a url, screenshots all of the banners at that url, and then bundles them in a zip file and returns that file to client for download.

**Front end code:**

```
fetch(`/dcsgrab?tearsheetUrl=${screenShotData}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        zipBlob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(data.zipFile.data)], {type: "octet/stream"});
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(zipBlob);
        zipDownload = document.createElement("a");

        setMessageData(data.message);
        setZipData(zipBlob);

        zipDownload.href = url;
        zipDownload.download = "screenshot-download.zip";
        document.body.appendChild(zipDownload);
        zipDownload.click();
      });
  };
```

**Back end code:**

```
app.get('/dcsgrab', (request, response) => {
    const zip = new AdmZip();

    (async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: true,
            executablePath: executablePath(),
            args: [
              '--no-sandbox',
              '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
              '--single-process',
            ],
        });

        let screenshotCounter = 1;

        const page = await browser.newPage();

        page.setViewport({width: 1280, height: 6000, deviceScaleFactor: PIXEL_DENSITY});

        await page.goto(request.query.tearsheetUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

        /**
       * Checks if the pagination button is active
       * @return {Promise.<Boolean>} Promise which resolves with a true boolean if the button is active
       */
      async function isNextButtonActive() {
        return await page.evaluate((selector) => {
          return !document.querySelector(selector).disabled;
        }, NEXT_SELECTOR);
      }

      /**
       * Clicks the pagination button
       * @return {Promise} Promise which resolves when the element matching selector is successfully clicked. The Promise will be rejected if there is no element matching selector
       */
      async function clickNextButton() {
        return await page.click(NEXT_SELECTOR, {delay: 100});
      }

      /**
       * Waits for the loading spinner widget to go away, indicating the iframes have been added to the page
       * @return {Promise.undefined}
       */
      async function waitForLoadingWidget() {
        return await page.waitForSelector('.preview-loading-widget', {hidden: true}).then(() => {
          console.log('Loading widget is gone');
        })
          .catch(e => {
            console.log(e.message);
          });
      }

      /**
       * Screenshot the creative elements on the current page
       * @return {Promise.<Array>} Promise which resolves with an array of clipping paths
       */
        async function getScreenShots() {
            const rects = await page.$$eval(PREVIEW_SELECTOR, iframes => {
              return Array.from(iframes, (el) => {
                const {x, y, width, height} = el.getBoundingClientRect();

                return {
                  left: x,
                  top: y,
                  width,
                  height,
                  id: el.id,
                };
              });
            }, PREVIEW_SELECTOR).catch(e => {
              console.error(e.message);
            });

            return Promise.all(rects.map(async (rect) => {
              return await page.screenshot({
                clip: {
                  x: rect.left,
                  y: rect.top,
                  width: rect.width,
                  height: rect.height,
                },
              }).then((content) => {
                zip.addFile(`screenshot-${screenshotCounter++}.png`, Buffer.from(content, "utf8"), `screenshot ${screenshotCounter++} saved`);
                console.log(`${rect.id} element captured and stored in zip`);
              })
                .catch((e) => {
                  console.error(e.message);
                });
            }));
        }

        // Wait a bit then take screenshots
      await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, DELAY_FOR_ANIMATION));
      await getScreenShots().catch((e) => console.error(e.message));

        // Continue taking screenshots till there are no pages left
      while (await isNextButtonActive()) {
        await clickNextButton();
        await waitForLoadingWidget();
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, DELAY_FOR_ANIMATION)),
        await getScreenShots().catch((e) => console.error(e.message));
      }

        await browser.close();

        const zipToSend = zip.toBuffer();

        response.json({ 
            message: 'Screenshots are done!\nPlease check the zip file that was just downloaded.',
            zipFile: zipToSend
        });
    })();
});
```

**Heroku logs:**

```
2023-03-23T19:27:43.174105+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2023-03-23T19:27:43.189825+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2023-03-23T19:27:44.190045+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2023-03-23T19:27:44.368177+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2023-03-23T19:27:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2023-03-23T19:28:07.523862+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2023-03-23T19:28:09.144631+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-03-23T19:28:09.144660+00:00 app[web.1]: > preview-sheet-grabber-react@1.0.0 start
2023-03-23T19:28:09.144661+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server/server.js
2023-03-23T19:28:09.144661+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-03-23T19:28:09.428387+00:00 app[web.1]: Server is listening on port 21309
2023-03-23T19:28:09.838525+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2023-03-23T19:28:10.596907+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=dcsgrab.herokuapp.com request_id=f0b15bcd-7eb4-4028-b5a9-2a6f76496c05 fwd="24.16.69.155" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=86ms status=200 bytes=944 protocol=https
2023-03-23T19:28:10.699774+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.1910c761.js" host=dcsgrab.herokuapp.com request_id=e775658f-f56d-4db8-bcb2-71de15b0d87d fwd="24.16.69.155" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=218121 protocol=https
2023-03-23T19:28:11.706348+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.69947f1d.css" host=dcsgrab.herokuapp.com request_id=5340c5b9-b516-4a5a-99f5-851b421b1949 fwd="24.16.69.155" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=3167 protocol=https
2023-03-23T19:28:11.818395+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/css/main.69947f1d.css.map" host=dcsgrab.herokuapp.com request_id=ffcf15de-1af4-4dee-83d1-99c0c811c73f fwd="24.16.69.155" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=5370 protocol=https
2023-03-23T19:28:11.820299+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/js/main.1910c761.js.map" host=dcsgrab.herokuapp.com request_id=e7c588ad-c085-4a12-bd1b-d3c4433d48de fwd="24.16.69.155" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=746644 protocol=https
2023-03-23T19:28:11.907618+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/essence_mediacom_logo-nobg-color_corrected.764800408369a0f7cf88.png" host=dcsgrab.herokuapp.com request_id=f1f5ed8c-eda8-46a1-af0f-8e87e8d2d615 fwd="24.16.69.155" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=16759 protocol=https
2023-03-23T19:28:11.993490+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/static/media/essencemediacom_icon.a48332799f21c2163415.png" host=dcsgrab.herokuapp.com request_id=05b087a5-cccc-4efb-9da4-d4b9ae3af678 fwd="24.16.69.155" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=14971 protocol=https
2023-03-23T19:28:12.189730+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/essencemediacom_icon.png" host=dcsgrab.herokuapp.com request_id=5921b175-24b7-43ef-8db8-1a3df51588ad fwd="24.16.69.155" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=200 bytes=14971 protocol=https
2023-03-23T19:28:12.473057+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/manifest.json" host=dcsgrab.herokuapp.com request_id=bfa7629b-b6ad-49c1-a4a0-bffb968bfbb6 fwd="24.16.69.155" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=787 protocol=https
2023-03-23T19:28:12.555689+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/logo192.png" host=dcsgrab.herokuapp.com request_id=174be88c-84fd-4046-8862-35c77bcef675 fwd="24.16.69.155" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=5622 protocol=https
2023-03-23T19:28:38.626764+00:00 app[web.1]: safe-frame-1 element captured and stored in zip
2023-03-23T19:28:39.116534+00:00 app[web.1]: safe-frame-5 element captured and stored in zip
2023-03-23T19:28:39.497607+00:00 app[web.1]: safe-frame-2 element captured and stored in zip
2023-03-23T19:28:39.954761+00:00 app[web.1]: safe-frame-4 element captured and stored in zip
2023-03-23T19:28:40.270808+00:00 app[web.1]: safe-frame-3 element captured and stored in zip
2023-03-23T19:28:41.373398+00:00 app[web.1]: Loading widget is gone
2023-03-23T19:28:47.380186+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/dcsgrab?tearsheetUrl=https://www.google.com/doubleclick/preview/dynamic/previewsheet/CMP6kgUQ3cxBGLbTkhUg97ss" host=dcsgrab.herokuapp.com request_id=8d21b818-58e6-4f76-bd08-2d00050801b4 fwd="24.16.69.155" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2023-03-23T19:28:56.769792+00:00 app[web.1]: safe-frame-8 element captured and stored in zip
2023-03-23T19:28:57.162674+00:00 app[web.1]: safe-frame-7 element captured and stored in zip
2023-03-23T19:28:57.598963+00:00 app[web.1]: safe-frame-6 element captured and stored in zip
2023-03-23T19:28:57.985009+00:00 app[web.1]: safe-frame-9 element captured and stored in zip
2023-03-23T19:28:58.436801+00:00 app[web.1]: safe-frame-10 element captured and stored in zip
2023-03-23T19:28:58.884653+00:00 app[web.1]: Loading widget is gone
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the official Heroku [error code H12](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout) it says:

> An HTTP request took longer than 30 seconds to complete

So your server might not be able to generate a response within 30 seconds for hitting the endpoint `/dcsgrab` and hence the error generated by Heroku.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I read that too, the challenge I'm having right now though is how to go about figuring out why it's taking longer than 30 seconds to complete and how I can go about mitigating that. I may close this question and open a different one specifically asking about this (after I make my own attempts at figuring it out).